# Mutual Inductance and the Dot Convention

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conventions, notation, inductance

Can anyone please explain me, the dot convention in coil systems (Mutual and self inductance) with some related images to understand..?

Comment: Did you Google or check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_inductance#Coupled_inductors)

Comment: ya. but, I didn't get the explanation in there, I need a explanation with images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find [this article (with pictures)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_convention) helpful for dot convention and this one for [mutual inductance](http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/mutual-inductance/).  Let me know if this doesn't clear it up.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers and provide a short explanation of both concepts.

Comment: There's not much to say, it's just a "which end up" question. To save you clicking the link, the key sentence from the article is: "When the current increases in the direction from the dot to the inductor, then positive voltage is induced at the dots of all the coupled inductors (including the original inductor due to self inductance)."